# Add new columns into an existing table and Update them using values from a cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, sql-update, cursor, alter

In the picture there is an example of the table I have and the table I need to create.

I have to calculate some values using the table Testing, then and add some new columns(Id2x and Id3x) to it and update these columns using the values I calculated. I found out that the problem is in trying to create the columns and them changing it. If I already had the columns id2x and id3x in my table i can update the table as long as I comment the line `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Alter table Testing add (id2X NUMBER, id3X NUMBER)';`

[image: Table to be updated using cursor]

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  CURSOR cursorP IS
        SELECT id, (2*id) as id2X, (3*id)as id3X
        FROM Testing
        FOR UPDATE OF id2X, id3X;
BEGIN          
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Alter table Testing add (id2X NUMBER, id3X NUMBER)';

  FOR line IN cursorP LOOP
    UPDATE Testing 
    SET id2X = line.id2X,
        id3X = line.id3X
    WHERE current of cursorP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

ERROR:

> ORA-06550: line 10, column 33:
>       PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ID3X": invalid identifier
>       ORA-06550: line 9, column5:
>       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>       06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>       *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot to say what is the problem you want us to help you with.Is there any error you have encoutered when you run this block?

Comment: The error code is in portuguese that's why i did not post it here, but i tried to translate and it is there now

Comment: Are you going to make this block a procedure?or is this a one time execution block?

Comment: i need to execute the script above just one time

Comment: I found out that If i already had the columns id2x and id3x in my table i can update the table as long as I comment the line EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Alter table Testing add (id2X NUMBER, id3X NUMBER)';

Comment: You cant alter/add a column and insert a value to it simultaneously. You can alter the table first then execute the block. try the codes below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its just a one time execution block, just move the alter statement outside the block. try this

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Alter table Testing add (id2X NUMBER, id3X NUMBER);

DECLARE
  CURSOR cursorP IS
        SELECT id, (2*id) as id2X, (3*id)as id3X
        FROM Testing
        FOR UPDATE OF id2X, id3X;
BEGIN          


  FOR line IN cursorP LOOP
    UPDATE Testing 
    SET id2X = line.id2X,
        id3X = line.id3X
    WHERE current of cursorP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```